# Insert if not exist in db, do nothing if exist in db and delete if not exist in list

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core-2.2

```
public class Ingredient
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId IngredientId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<IngredientSideEffectItem> SideEffects { get; set; } 
}

public class IngredientSideEffectItem
{
    public ObjectId SideEffectId { get; set; }
    public long Counter{ get; set; }
}


public async Task UpdateIngredient(Ingredient s)
{
    FilterDefinition<Ingredient> filter = 
        Builders<Ingredient>.Filter.Eq(l => l.IngredientId, , s.IngredientId);
    UpdateDefinition<Ingredient> update = 
        Builders<Ingredient>.Update
            .Set(x => x.SideEffects, s.SideEffects)
            .Set(x => x.IsActive,s.IsActive) 

    UpdateResult result = await db.Ingredients.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}
```

I want to insert items `s.SideEffects` to into `x.SideEffects`. But if item exist in db - ignore; if not exist in db - insert; and if exist in db and not in list -  delete from db. How to write this query?

Comment: You need to write your own code for that. The logic is to retrieve the existing side effects from the database and compare against the list and identify which records to insert and which ones to delete from the list and then perform insert and delete on those records